How to actively, rather than passively, get the latest position of an Anchor?
On iOS, each ARAnchor is an NSObject, so I just need to save its reference and get its transform property whenever needed.
However, on Vision OS, let's take WorldAnchor as an example. It's a struct, which means saving its "reference" actually creates a copy.
Subsequently, when getting its originFromAnchorTransform property, you only get the position of that copy created at that moment.

Even though each WorldAnchor has an ID, there is no method like WorldTrackingProvider.getAnchor(by: UUID) available.
In other words, I have no means to actively get the latest position of a WorldAnchor.

You can always get the latest position of an anchor through anchorUpdates. The code is similar to this:
class Model { 
    var allTrackerAnchor: [WorldAnchor] = []
    
    func worldTrackingUpdate() async {
        for await anchor in worldInfo.anchorUpdates {
            if let index = self.allTrackerAnchor.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == anchor.anchor.id }) {
                self.allTrackerAnchor[index] = anchor.anchor
            } else {
                self.allTrackerAnchor.append(anchor.anchor)
            }
        }
    }
}

You only need to integrate it into your RealityView as follows:
RealityView { content in
    // Your content setup
}
.task {
    await model.worldTrackingUpdate()
}

This setup ensures that your anchors are always updated with the latest position information.
